# Web service ASMX está obsoleto?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-service, api, rest

Me deparei com a necessidade de consumir um Web Service ASMX. Até então tinha apenas consumido RESTful APIs. Notei que o mesmo é bem diferente de uma RESTful API, por exemplo.

Dado a forma que é configurado, parece que o mesmo já foi deixado de lado, que é algo bem antigo.

É recomendado utilizar um Web Service ASMX? Alguém ainda utiliza o mesmo para criar um Web Service do zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defina obsoleto.

Se considerar que ele é usado para o ASP.NET Clássico, com WebForms e coisas do tipo, podemos dizer que sim.

Mas ele ainda é considerado um componente válido e suportado no .NET. Pode usar.

A pergunta é se deve. Não há atualizações em cima dele, e há uma recomendação geral, não exatamente oficial de não usá-lo mais.

Quem tem uma base grande usá-lo pode ter algum ganho mantendo a continuidade. Se vai só consumir o que já existe, pode ser interessante.

Se tem pouca coisa e é fácil converter eu acho que iria de Web API usando o ASP.NET Core. Só você pode avaliar se compensa o esforço. O ganho não será grande no uso, talvez mais organização no desenvolvimento, ou na escala.

Comment: Dado o que disse, sobre o ASP.NET Core e, adicionando que tem sido um grande sucesso desde o lançamento juntamente com o suporte da comunidade,seria correto dizer que atualmente é melhor criar uma API em ASP.NET Core do que em ASMX? Não vejo explicação para utilizar uma tecnologia antiga que provavelmente só continua disponível devido a grande quantidade de aplicações que a utilizam.

Comment: Sim, é bem melhor.